# Calc Challenge Problem

Tags: calculus

If $x^3 f(x)+f(x)^3+f(x^3)=3$ and It is known that $f(1)=2$, What is $f'(1)$?

By letting $x=1$ in $f(x)$, I got that $x^3=-\frac{7}{2}$... What can I do now?

Answer (score 3):

To find $f'(1)$, you must use [implicit differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function#Implicit_differentiation) on the original equation.  Take the derivative with respect to $x$ of both sides; only then plug in $x=1$.  You will have an equation with $x$ (which is $1$), $f(1)$ (which is $2$), and $f'(1)$ (which you need to solve for).

Your calculations show that $x$ is both $1$ and the cube root of $-7/2$, which is of course impossible.  The $3$ on the right side should actually be $12$, but this doesn't affect the solution method outlined above, as the derivative of both $3$ and $12$ is just zero.

Comment: So would doing this be correct?
d/dx((x^3)(f(x))+d/dx(f(x))^3+d/dx(f(x^3))=0
which simplifies down to 2x(f(x))+x^3(f'(x))+3f(x)^2(f'(x))+f'(x^3)=0
Then plugging in x=1 to simplify down to 
4+f'(1)+12f'(1)+f'(1)=0
and from here f'(1)=-2/7 ???

Comment: Please post your solution in MathJax, as it is almost unreadable in this form.  Also, you should post this as a separate question, or as an alternate solution.